# How to set different path for php error_log file?

Tags: php, apache, error-logging

I have very limited access to settings on my server, so I need to manually set `ini_set('log_errors', 1);` in my scripts. But can I in same way change the path to the error_log file, to have it in my reach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual says](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) it's *PHP_INI_ALL*, so you *can* set it at runtime.

- Notably that'll have no effect to any messages generated prior calling [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini_set).
- Better option would be to use one of the SAPI-dependant configuration schemes (`.user.ini` or `.htaccess`)

Also take in mind that the destined log path needs to be writeable by the Apache or FPM process, of course.

Comment: (CW + duplicate links, because I feel they're more detailed anyway.)